# How to set Highcharts data series option with $.getJson

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I am trying to use Highcharts to render a bar chart that will get a json array of objects from an external api. The x axis will be the city and the y axis the number of people in that city. When I try to set the series data option to the json array 'I get a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined' error in chrome.

Here is the chart which I am using.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var options = {
    chart : {
        renderTo: 'container1',


        title: {
            text: 'Chart 1',
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'city'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'people'
            }

        },
        tooltip: {

            formatter: function(){
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                this.x + ': ' + this.y;
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: []
        }]
     },
 };

    $.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/logitems_list', function(data){
    options.series.data[0] = data;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

    });     
});
```

Here is an example of the json structure which I get back

```
[{"id":1,"state":"Massachusetts","city":"Boston"},    {"id":2,"state":"Massachusetts","city":"Boston"},{"id":3,"state":"Massachusetts","city":"Boston"},{"id":4,"state":"Massachusetts","city":"Boston"}]
```

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this. Your `options` is incorrectly formatted. When you are trying to set the data within the JSON-callback it is incorrectly addressed. Your JSON is also not at all in a data-format that Highcharts accepts. Also your not receiving any population value, so you have nothing to use for your y-axis.

Comment: thanks. Does the json need to be converted into just an array? Also was not sure how to set the options to the data in the function call back.

Comment: Well, where will you be getting the population? Hard to suggest a way to achieve it when you don't have the required data available.

Comment: the id field is a user who is registered on the site so they can be the population.

Comment: At the beginning please visit the page and check how json should look like http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/color-axis then adapt your json to correct form.